# memory-mapped files in C

Tags: c, memory, file-io, transparency, library-interposition

I was playing around with memory-mapped files in C and was wondering if there
is a way to replace the FILE * from fopen with a memory mapped file transparently.

Example:

```
FILE * fp = g_fopen(...);

//Program does things to this fp.

fclose();
```

But instead, is it possible to have FILE *fp = my_fopen(...)

Where my own function would open a file on disk mmap it, maybe change contents and then pass back the FILE * without the program seeing anything 
different except the new my_fopen() and my_fclose().

Is this possible to do without having to rewrite the way the operations are done in the program?

Comment: These answers are for *ix systems, answer for Windows is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369445/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-fdopen-for-handles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic words are "library interposition". Here's a good tutorial: <s>http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html</s>

---

When Oracle purchased sun a lot of articles seem to have disappeared and/or aren't accessible through Oracle's website.

Here's some links that, for the time being, are functional:

- This is the original article as published in 2001: [Building Library Interposers for Fun and Profit](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926) (Dr. Dobbs)
- The developers.sun.com link was a repost by the original author, possibly with changes from the 2001 article; this is the repost: [Debugging and Performance Tuning with Library Interposers](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626005255/http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html) (Wayback Machine)
- The [Linker & Libraries Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter3-26/index.html) for Sun Studio / Oracle Solaris Studio.  It covers the topic of library interposition with more technical details.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of memory-mapped file IO is not to go through system calls for reads and writes, but rely on VM/buffer cache to do the work. If you hide the fact that the file has been memory mapped, what is the advantage here? How would you know at what address the file is mapped?

Comment: The perceived advantage for me was the ability to modify existing calls to do what I wish. Maybe inserting custom actions before a file is read or change the way it is read in without having to alter existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. You can use read/write on a file you have mmaped, so your my_fopen
would look like this

```
FILE * my_fopen()
{
    FILE * myfp
    myfp = fopen(...);
    mmap(fileno(myfp),...);
    return myfp;
}
```