# Is there a Windows equivalent to fdopen for HANDLEs?

Tags: c, winapi, stdio

In Unix, if you have a file descriptor (e.g. from a socket, pipe, or inherited from your parent process), you can open a buffered I/O `FILE*` stream on it with [`fdopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).

Is there an equivalent on Windows for `HANDLE`s?  If you have a `HANDLE` that was inherited from your parent process (different from stdin, stdout, or stderr) or a pipe from `CreatePipe`, is it possible to get a buffered `FILE*` stream from it?  MSDN does document [`_fdopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dye30d82%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but that works with integer file descriptors returned by `_open`, not generic `HANDLE`s.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unfortunately, `HANDLE`s are completely different beasts from `FILE*`s and file descriptors. The CRT ultimately handles files in terms of `HANDLE`s and associates those `HANDLE`s to a file descriptor. Those file descriptors in turn backs the structure pointer by `FILE*`.

Fortunately, there is a section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kdfaxaay.aspx) that describes functions that "provide a way to change the representation of the file between a **FILE** structure, a file descriptor, and a Win32 file handle":

> - `_fdopen`, `_wfdopen`: Associates a stream with a file that was
>     previously opened for low-level I/O and returns a pointer to the open
>     stream.
> - `_fileno`: Gets the file descriptor associated with a stream.
> - `_get_osfhandle`: Return operating-system file handle associated
>     with existing C run-time file descriptor
> - `_open_osfhandle`: Associates C run-time file descriptor with an
>     existing operating-system file handle.

Looks like what you need is [`_open_osfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) followed by [`_fdopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dye30d82.aspx) to obtain a `FILE*` from a `HANDLE`.

Here's an example involving `HANDLE`s obtained from `CreateFile()`. When I tested it, it shows the first 255 characters of the file "test.txt" and appends " --- Hello World! --- " at the end of the file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = CreateFile("test.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
        OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)h, _O_APPEND | _O_RDONLY);
        if(fd != -1)
        {
            FILE* f = _fdopen(fd, "a+");
            if(f != 0)
            {
                char rbuffer[256];
                memset(rbuffer, 0, 256);
                fread(rbuffer, 1, 255, f);
                printf("read: %s\n", rbuffer);
                fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR); // Switch from read to write
                const char* wbuffer = " --- Hello World! --- \n";
                fwrite(wbuffer, 1, strlen(wbuffer), f);
                fclose(f); // Also calls _close()
            }
            else
            {
                _close(fd); // Also calls CloseHandle()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CloseHandle(h);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for pipes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elegant way of doing this instead of CreateFile: specify "N" in fopen(). It's a Microsoft-specific extension to fopen, but since this code is platform-specific anyway, it's ok. When called with "N", fopen adds _O_NOINHERIT flag when calling _open internally.

Based on this:
[Windows C Run-Time _close(fd) not closing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957563/windows-c-run-time-closefd-not-closing-file)