# Casting System::IO::FileStream^ to FILE*

Tags: c++-cli, managed

I am working on refactoring a large amount of code from an unmanaged C++ assembly into a C# assembly. There is currently a mixed-mode assembly going between the two with, of course, a mix of managed and unmanaged code. There is a function I am trying to call in the unmanaged C++ which relies on FILE*s (as defined in stdio.h). This function ties into a much larger process which cannot be refactored into the C# code yet, but which *now* needs to be called from the managed code.

I have searched but cannot find a definitive answer to what kind of underlying system pointer the System::IO::FileStream class uses. Is this just applied on top of a FILE*? Or is there some other way to convert a FileStream^ to a FILE*? I found FileStream::SafeFileHandle, on which I can call DangerousGetHandle().ToPointer() to get a native void*, but I'm just trying to be certain that if I cast this to FILE* that I'm doing the right thing...?

```
void Write(FILE *out)
{
    Data->Write(out); // huge bulk of code, writing the data
}

virtual void __clrcall Write(System::IO::FileStream ^out)
{
    // is this right??
    FILE *pout = (FILE*)out->SafeFileHandle->DangerousGetHandle().ToPointer();
    Write(pout);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your best bet. There doesn't seem to be any guarantee the "OS file handle" is actually a FILE* though. But if it is, it seems unlikely to change. You're probably going to have to prevent the handle from being released while in native code, via a GC.KeepAlive on the out stream.

Comment: Does that atually make any difference? If the data is large, I'd have expected fairly little overhead...

Comment: No, FILE is a strict C runtime abstraction, in no way related to a Windows handle.  You can hack this with _fdopen() for 32-bit code.

Comment: @MatsPetersson the issue isn't the speed of the code, it's the amount of it. There are probably well over a thousand lines (just for writing this particular data file) of C++ code that needs to be refactored into C# (moving away from a mixed-mode assembly into a pure C# one). Writing the file is too big to refactor yet, but I am refactoring other parts of the class which means I need to be able to call the native, unmanaged Write method from the managed code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [`_open_osfhandle` followed by `_fdopen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369445/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-fdopen-for-handles).

Casting is not magic. Just because the input and types output are right for your situation doesn't mean the values are.

Comment: I definitely understand that casting is NOT magic, but I haven't done much Windows-specific programming in C++. Whether or not the underlying pointer was of the FILE type was part of my question. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Well, even if `HANDLE` did _wrap_ a `FILE*`, that pointer probably wouldn't be retrievable by a cast.

Comment: The point being that I didn't even realize that `HANDLE` was a type unto itself.

Comment: Even with a valid HANDLE, _open_osfhandle seems to always return -1.

`virtual void __clrcall Write(FileStream ^out)
{
    if (!out->CanWrite) {} /* throw */
    SafeFileHandle^ safeHandle = out->SafeFileHandle;
    if (safeHandle->IsInvalid) {} /* throw */
    if (safeHandle->IsClosed) {} /* throw */
    void *handle = safeHandle->DangerousGetHandle().ToPointer();
    int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)handle, _O_APPEND | _O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {} /* throw */
    FILE *fp = _fdopen(fd, "a+");
    if (fp == NULL) {} /* throw */
    Write(fp);
    System::GC::KeepAlive(out);
}`