# string FILE stdio compatible?

Tags: c, windows, string, stdio

Is there anything like a string file in stdio/string/stdlib ? I mean a special way to fopen a FILE stream, which actually directs the writes to an internal buffer and takes care of buffer allocation/reallocation ? After fclose, the text should be available as null-terminated char[] or similar.

I need to interface to legacy code that receives a FILE* as an argument and writes to it, and I'd prefer to avoid writing to a temporary disk file.

Other forms of storage could do instead of char[] (f.i. string), but a FILE* pointer must be available.

I am looking for an alternative to creating a temporary disk file.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be tagged as C?

Comment: Actually it will be called from C++ CLI.

Comment: Why not use the STL?

Comment: How will STL support a Posix FILE ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean, but why not use a char * and realloc when necessary?

Comment: On Linux you can use `fopencookie` or `open_memstream` to do this. I don't think Windows has an equivalent.

Comment: @Josh: Because the legacy code will not tell me when a realloc is required. That should be handled by the string FILE, which receives the write requests.

Comment: No, there isn't anything like STL in C. You'll need to write your own buffer struct and reallocate space, as needed.

Comment: You can get a std::fstream from a FILE * [on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746168/how-to-construct-a-c-fstream-from-a-posix-file-descriptor).

Comment: Why is this tagged posix when you said you use C++/CLI? Which OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: @interjay: it seems that open_memstream is exactly what I need (there's also a fmemopen but it doesn't grow the buffer). fopencookie  could do as well as it allows you to write your own hooks. I would need a Windows equivalent of one of these.

Comment: @interjay: the calling code is written in C++ CLI with MSVC, and invokes a native API that uses Posix.

Comment: If you aren't actually on a POSIX system then I suggest removing that tag.

Comment: @interjay: The POSIX tag is there to stress C POSIX library compliance (stdio).

Comment: If this is for Window only, I'd tag the question [windows].

Comment: @YvesDaoust stdio is part of the C standard. POSIX is a standard which includes that but also a lot more (for example, it defines `open_memstream`, which isn't in the C standard) and isn't directly supported on Windows.

Comment: Note that `fmemopen()` and `open_memstream()` are not in POSIX.1-2001, but only in POSIX.1-2008.  There are still a good number of systems that comply with the former but not the latter, and on such systems you are unlikely to find those functions available.  I'm not sure whether Windows is among them.

Comment: If you want a solution that is based only on the C standard library (for maximum portability, including to Windows) then you are out of luck.  The standard library does not provide a `FILE` view of memory, nor any mechanism by which you could portably roll your own.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I just need a solution that supports the FILE type and runs under Windows. I don't care about portability.

Answer (score 0):

[fmemopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) & [open_memstream](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html) are in the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) 2008 standard, probably inspired by GNU libc [string streams](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html), and give in-memory  `FILE*` streams.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12249610/841108) quite similar to yours, and also [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253726/841108).

BTW, many operating systems [have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software) RAM based or virtual memory based filesystems (à la [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs))

If you are coding in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (not in C) and perhaps for some earlier C++ standard  you can of course use [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)-s

So you could use `open_memstream` on Posix, and some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5253726/841108) solution on Windows (just with `#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE > 200809L` per [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) ...)

The C standard does not provide (yet) any in-memory `FILE` streams, so if you need them you *have* to code or use *platform-specific* functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, these do not appear to be supported by MS, nor fopencookie nor funopen.

Comment: But then, you might use a RAM based file.

Comment: That's what I am looking for from the beginning.

Comment: Follow the links in my answer!

Comment: Using an "external" RAM disk is a pretty heavy solution, and you have to give it a fixed size anyway :( Using stringstream is of no use here as it does not emulate a FILE.

Comment: It (using a RAM disk) is a configuration and sysadmin issue.

Comment: Yep, this application is intended to be copied and run on any machine without an installation. So far my best option is a real file with a temporary attribute (tmpfs), hoping the rights are granted.

Answer (score 0):

Create the temporary file using `CreateFile(... FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE ...)` and then [convert the `HANDLE` to `FILE*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369445/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-fdopen-for-handles).

You said you didn't like a write to a temporary file, so these flags to CreateFile are a strong hint to Windows to keep the file in cache if possible. And if Windows would run of of RAM, even a `char[]` can end up in a swap file anyway.

Comment: Yep, that's my current solution. I don't mind that there can indeed be disk accesses, I am more worried by the need to access the file system and be allowed to do so.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Why would that be a problem? `GetTempPath` should give you a writeable directory. Create a GUID for a filename and you don't have collisions. But if you do have a " current solution"  you really should include that in the question!