# Rewrite code: Output from file to char* ~> is FILE* to virtual file in RAM possible?

Tags: c++, c, file-descriptor

I have some old 3rd party `C++` code that writes to/reads from a file using `fopen()`, `fprintf()/fscanf()`. I need to rewrite it, so that the whole thing that is serialised is returned as a `char*`.

Is it possible to just "open" a virtual file (with unknown size) in memory and then copy the output to a `char*`, so that I don't have to touch the `fprintf()`-with-`filedescriptor` part at all?

Comment: You can't return all that data "as a `char*`" (unless it's very small); you can only return a `char*` that points to the data in memory. Be very careful about ownership semantics.

Comment: Ok, I return it "via" a char* - I think it's pretty clear what I meant. ;)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @rob: Linux. But the more versatile the solution, the better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [memory-mapped files in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911296/memory-mapped-files-in-c)

Comment: @snøreven: Just making sure. More Stack Overflowers than I could possibly count did _not_ mean the same thing that you did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `mmap` on Linux and other UNIXes.

Comment: But with mmap I need to know the maximum mem size before, don't I?